# Can I Go Copper to Pex/CPVC

Tags: plumbing, copper, copper-pipe, cpvc

I've got some 1/2 inch copper piping and a capped pipe.  The tee was originally used to run water to a washing machine cold water line (hot was not run as it was not being used).  Due to home renovations we want to move the washer back to this location, so will need to run the water line again.

(I'm hoping for a no-solder resolution here.)

With the below image, is it possible to cut the copper, above and below the tee, use a push to connect type connector to the copper, and have the other end be a CPVC connector, add CPVC, add a tee, and run the line for the washer?

Is this possible and a good setup?

[image]

Comment: Rather shortsighted to have cut the pipe when the washer was moved, and cut it flush with the wall at that. Approach seems overly complicated if there's enough stub on the Tee to connect to, which appears to be the case.

Comment: Depends. Can you spread that pipe once you've cut it, or is it locked in place?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, that stub looks smaller than 1/2. I don't think I'd use it.

Comment: @isherwood - what do you mean can I "spread that pipe once you've cut it"?

Comment: @Ecnerwal - def a poor choice on my part.  Trying to remedy at this point tho.

Comment: Which of those words is confusing? Push fittings require movement in an outward direction. Do you have that capability? We have no context here.

Comment: Do you mean the copper above/below the tee?  If that is the case, yes there is plenty of room to move the piping up/down.

Comment: Then there should be no problem. I'm not sure what your concern was to begin with. If you can find fittings to suit, and you're using the fewest practical number of them, that's success.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there were push to connect copper - to - cpvc connectors.  When I check my local box stores website, I do not see any relevant results of what I'm after.

Comment: Walking into the store often yields far better results than browsing a web site. You _can_ find helpful people there (but not always). Also, if the home center fails you, look to an actual plumbing store. I'm curious, though, why you're going to CPVC instead of PEX. You only mention PEX once, in the title question, but not again.

Comment: I've never used PEX before - I've heard it's what everything is going to.  Would I be better to go Copper to PEX?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a push connector that doesn't support CPVC. [Sharkbite says](https://www.sharkbite.com/us/en/brass-push-to-connect/fittings)

> Push-to-connect fittings are compatible with more than five types of pipe including PEX, copper, CPVC, PE-RT & HDPE.

PVC is slightly different, but also available.

Buy a push connector that has a threaded connection on one end. With the water off, remove the cap and screw on your push connector (don't forget the pipe dope). This avoids cutting the pipe further and lets you run your CPVC as mentioned.

Comment: To you from the image does it look like there is enough "room" for me to cut off the cap, and add a push connector to copper with threaded on the other side?  How do I connect the cpvc to the threads?   Just push the pipe in and glue it?

Comment: It looks like you have a threaded cap. which is why I mentioned using a [threaded push connector](https://www.sharkbite.com/us/en/brass-push-to-connect/fittings/adapters/brass-push-female-adapter-elbow). Elbow it off with that and you can push your CPVC into the other end. I wouldn't cut the pipe unless absolutely needed.

Comment: In the image, if I cut off the cap that is on there now.  Does it look like there is enough room for me to add a push connector?

Comment: It's hard to say. From the angle of the shot, it looks like you could cut the threaded portion off if you removed the cap first. Use a scoring cutter on it.

Answer (score 1):

> I wasn't sure if there were push to connect copper - to - cpvc connectors.

https://www.sharkbite.com/us/en/resources/blog/connecting-copper-to-pex-fast-with-sharkbite-fittings

https://www.sharkbite.com/us/en/brass-push-to-connect/fittings/couplings/brass-push-coupling

*Innovative SharkBite push-to-connect pipe repair couplings make for quick and easy installations. Connect two pieces of PEX, copper, CPVC, PE-RT and / or SDR-9 HDPE pipe in any combination. Approved for underground and behind-the-wall applications, brass couplings with push-to-connect design can be installedpermanently or provide a temporary fix while you work. Choose the right model for your pipe type, measure and mark the correct insertion depth and push to make the connection.*

> Can I Go Copper to Pex/CPVC... and everything else you asked

yes

> When I check my local box stores

don't do that.  go to supplyhouse.com, and ask them.  Given the picture you posted which seems that the tee is going against the wall, just cut out 1-2 feet of the 3/4 copper pipe and put a new tee oriented in an ergonomic usable manner and run pipe/tubing appropriately.  Doubt you can salvage what little bit of stub from the tee that is against the wall with a push on connector- maybe could be done with solder.

> I've never used PEX before...

search youtube to educate yourself on what is practical to use in your case and how, and plumbing in general, this is one example there are many:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywtnOq1ExqQ